# How to change background color of the text of hover window?

Tags: neovim

I have such binding that opens the hover window

```
vim.keymap.set('n', 'K', vim.lsp.buf.hover, bufopts)
```

As you can see the background color of the `let name2: {unknown}` is white (`#ffffff`). I would like to make it transparent

[image]

How can I change the background color of the text?

P.S. I use Lua as a configuration language

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! What LSP client is this? The one built-in to NeoVim?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble nvim-lsp

Comment: Changing NormalFloat should work.  Have a look at https://github.com/casonadams/walh

Answer (score 0):

That should be controlled by the `NormalFloat` highlight group. I have the following setting in Lua to make it "transparent" (same color as the buffer background):

```lua
local set_hl_for_floating_window = function()
  vim.api.nvim_set_hl(0, 'NormalFloat', {
    link = 'Normal',
  })
  vim.api.nvim_set_hl(0, 'FloatBorder', {
    bg = 'none',
  })
end

set_hl_for_floating_window()

vim.api.nvim_create_autocmd('ColorScheme', {
  pattern = '*',
  desc = 'Avoid overwritten by loading color schemes later',
  callback = set_hl_for_floating_window,
})
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try it as soon as possible and get back to you with feedback